# Black Screen in flutter when navigated to different page using gesturedetector in flutter. Says multiple heros share same tag

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-layout

I am building an application where Home ui looks like grid and when tapped on an individual tile of the grid user will be navigated to another page. But whenever it happens an error throws up. Here is the code not looking at syntactical errors. 
I did not use any hero widget. Though i get this error..

```
     body: Container(
       child: GridView.count(
         crossAxisCount: 2,
         children: <Widget>[ 
           Card(
             child: InkWell(
               onTap: (){
                 print('tapped pnemonia');
                 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> diagnosis()));
               },
               child: Center(
                 child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                     Text('Pnemonia'),
                     Image.asset('assets/images/lungs.jpg'),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the output error is the following:

```
I/flutter ( 6827): ├# Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
I/flutter ( 6827):
I/flutter ( 6827): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 6827): #0      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:265:11)
I/flutter ( 6827): #1      Hero._allHeroesFor.inviteHero (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:276:8)
I/flutter ( 6827): #2      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:295:21)
I/flutter ( 6827): #3      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #4      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #6      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #8      Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #9      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5534:16)
I/flutter ( 6827): #10     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #12     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #13     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #14     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #16     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #17     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #18     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #19     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5534:16)
I/flutter ( 6827): #20     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #21     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #22     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #23     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #24     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #25     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #26     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #27     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5534:16)
I/flutter ( 6827): #28     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #29     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #30     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #31     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #32     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #33     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #34     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #36     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #37     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #38     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #39     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5433:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #40     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #41     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #42     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #43     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #44     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #45     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #46     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): #47     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4272:14)
I/flutter ( 6827): #48     Hero._allHeroesFor.visitor (package:flutter/src/widgets/heroes.dart:308:15)
I/flutter ( 6827): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 6827): 
I/flutter ( 6827): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

this is the error that comes when i run the build.

Comment: can you post more code epecially where you use `hero` widget, use `Navigator`  and `Gesture detector` ?

Comment: i updated the code. Its complete now

Comment: I don't see any gesture detector or Hero widgets used anywhere..

Comment: thats the problem. I dont know where is the problem, but i think it is in card()

Comment: can you post all logs from the start so that we can verify the source loacation of the Hero widget.? may be not here if too long.

Comment: sure. Let me update it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204954/discussion-between-jithin-pal-and-harshvardhan-joshi).

Comment: I'll appreciate if you take some time to upvote and accept my answer or tell me if facing any problems in the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `multiple heroes on one route can't have the same tag` is possible when you try to use multiple `FloatingActionButtons` in one widget.

According to the documentation of `heroTag` in the `FloatingActionButton` :

> The tag to apply to the button's Hero widget.
>
> Defaults to a tag that matches other floating action buttons.
>
> Set this to null explicitly if you don't want the floating action
>   button to have a hero tag.
>
> If this is not explicitly set, then there can only be one
>   FloatingActionButton per route (that is, per screen), since otherwise
>   there would be a tag conflict (multiple heroes on one route can't have
>   the same tag). The material design specification recommends only using
>   one floating action button per screen.

To resolve your exception and Use multiple FAB in a single widget make sure to pass `Unique` object/value/string for `heroTag` in the FAB.

Note: If you don't pass a value to `heroTag` it creates a default value `<default FloatingActionButton tag>`. which is common for all FABs. So if they are in the same widget they'll be using duplicate `heroTag` which throws exception.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 3):

It might be late but, if you still confusing. I solved my problem by manually added new attribute `heroTag` in my FloatingActionButtons.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: 1, // put something different with this
            onPressed: (){
              counterBloc.add(CounterEvent.increment);
            },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: 2, // put something different with this
          onPressed: (){
            counterBloc.add(CounterEvent.decrement);
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Hope it's Help someone